# DAX Problem on how to create a column to select single values from another related multiple value column

Tags: powerbi, dax

Is there a way to create a DAX new column which returns single values from a related table with multiple values?

I have used RelatedTable, selectedvalues, Values functions. But it returns a syntax error that "the expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value".

Comment: Short answer is that you *must* use an aggregate function to do it, because you're looking from the One side to the Many side. The question is then which value(s) did you want to bring across? the first one? the smallest one? the newest one?

Comment: An example is a table with continents,  and countries. So each continent has a code, say Africa with code 33, and all African nations will have that code. So I want to create a column that will just select the single values code for each continent

Comment: Where/how did you intend to use this? if you're using something like a matrix, you could create a hierarchy and just drill down. Are you summing something (like Total Sales)? Without some context, it's hard to advise you what to do.

Comment: Pls paste the sample data and desired output